# What is the maths behind findpeaks function on matlab?"

Tags: matlab

How can I use maths to explain this matlab function?

https://ch.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html
[findpeaks function matlab link](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html)

findpeaks function

Comment: It is closed-source, we cannot know how it is implemented outside of what is described in the documentation page you linked.

Comment: @CrisLuengo However, the code is available. I can read the `findpeaks` code in matlab using command  `open findpeaks`and the code given.

Comment: From the code: "A local peak is defined as a data sample which is either larger than the two neighboring samples or is equal to Inf."

Comment: @David. Thanks. What do you mean by `Inf.`?

Comment: Matlab's representation of infinity.

Comment: @David, thanks. But what is the maths in finding the peaks? You can write an answer, and I can accept it.

Comment: It looks for values larger than the two on either side. That's it.

Comment: @David, It cannot be just only 1 sentences summary the whole function.

Comment: if `x(i-1)<x(i)` and `x(i)>x(i+1)` then you have found a peak at `x(i)`. That's literally all it's doing.

Comment: @David, thanks. so peak is `x(i)` and it find the left side and right side. Anymore information?

Comment: If `x=[1 2 3 1 1]` then the peak is 3 because it is bigger than 2 and 1. That's what Matlab is doing, it compares 2 to 1 and 3 -> not a peak. Then compare 3 to 2 and 1 -> is a peak. Then compare 1 to 3 and 1 -> not a peak. Finished. I really don't understand what you are asking this is the most basic idea of what it means to be a peak.

Comment: @David, thanks. How about it able to find several peaks in one signal. For example. `x=[1 3 4 3 3 3 1 10 1 3 2]`. the peak is `4`, `10`? I mean there are 2 peaks in a signal x

Comment: It does the test for all the elements of the vector (except first and last) any elements which are larger than their 2 neighbours are peaks.

Comment: @David, thanks. Sorry for asking again. I could not understand `except first and last of any elements`, what elements you refer to?

Comment: @David how is the prominence peak calculated??

Comment: The first and last element can't be a peak because they can't be larger than the elements on either side. The prominence is the minimum height above the two neighbouring points.

Comment: @David, thanks. What is the mathatical calculation for prominence peak?